# Published package cannot find module

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, mapbox-gl-js

I'm writing an npm package with TypeScript which uses the `mapbox-gl` module. Inside my npm package itself I can run `tsc` with no errors.

[image: Inside the package]

But after publishing it, when I try to import my module, I get an error that the `mapbox-gl` module cannot be found:

[image: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mapbox-gl']

Here is the package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "mapbox-gl": "^0.28.0",
  "@angular/core": "^2.2.4",
  "rollup": "0.36.4",
  "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.5"
}
```

The import which is outputing `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mapbox-gl'` when using the package:

```
import * as mapbox from 'mapbox-gl';
```

I'm rather confused why it works inside the package, but after publishing to npm and trying to use it this error shows?

It defiantly cannot be that mapbox-gl is not installed as I can find it in my node_modules and because i'm using Angular 2 the front end works fine.

If it helps here is a link to the package and github repo:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-mapbox

https://github.com/kuflink/angular2-mapbox

Comment: I've had a similar issue, my case was because  the package was in different location. Are you using typings? https://github.com/typings/typings

Comment: It seems that the dependency causing the error (mapbox-gl) is in the projects node_modules folder rather than my package's node_modules folder. I'm not sure why that is happening and if its causing the error.

Comment: That's due the way npm handles the packages